# No action when clicking on button; quote doesn't change

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have put together a simple quote generator, storing the quotes in an array. Following are the quote view controller interface and implementation files:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, retain)NSArray *myQuotes;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSMutableArray *movieQuotes;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *quote_text;

-(IBAction)quote_btn_touch:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize myQuotes;
@synthesize movieQuotes;
@synthesize quote_text;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  self.myQuotes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   @"Live and let live", 
                   @"Don't cry over spilt milk", 
                   @"Always look on the bright side of life", 
                   @"Nobody's perfect", 
                   @"Can't see the woods for the trees",
                   @"Better to have loved and lost than not loved at all",
                   @"The early bird catches the worm",
                   @"As slow as a wet week",
                   nil];

  quote_text = nil;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

-(IBAction)quote_btn_touch:(id)sender {
  // 1 - Get number of rows in array
  int array_tot = [self.myQuotes count];
  // 2 - Get random index
  int index = (arc4random() % array_tot);
  // 3 - Get the quote string for the index 
  NSString *my_quote = [self.myQuotes objectAtIndex:index];
  // 4 - Display the quote in the text view
  self.quote_text.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Quote:\n\n%@",  my_quote];      
}

@end
```

In the xib file, I connected the text view and button to the File's Owner, using quote_text and quote_btn_touch respectively.

Trouble is that when I click on the button, nothing happens. Any idea what I missed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your setting quote text to nil on viewDidLoad. If you get rid of that your code should work as long as you correctly bound the button to the viewcontroller function

```
quote_text = nil;
```

Comment: Thank you. I see that I should have put that under the viewDidUnload method instead of viewDidLoad. Thanks again!